# How can I make this program repeat/loop after first calculation

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to make this program ask the user what they would like to calculate after they have already calculated one problem instead of just ending.

I know i'm  to use a For Loop in this situation but in reality I am unsure as to how I should incorporate this

```
#WE ARE TRYING TO SPLIT THE OPTIONS INTO FUNCTIONS THAT CAN BE CALLED LATER DEPENDING ON THE INPUT


# THIS DETERMINES THE COMPOUND INTEREST
def calc_int():
    # SETS THE USER INPUT INTO VARIABLES AS 'int' OR 'float' THAT CAN BE USED IN LATER FORMULAS
    principal = int(input("What is the principal amount?"))
    rate = float(input("What is the rate amount? (Enter in decimal format)"))
    number = int(input("How many times will this be compounded yearly?"))
    time = int(input("How long will this be compounded for?"))

    # CALCULATES THE COMPOUND INTEREST AMOUNT
    exponent = number * time
    interest_amount = principal * (1 + rate / number) ** exponent

    # CALCULATES HOW MUCH WAS EARNED OR LOST
    earned_amount = interest_amount - principal

    # THIS WILL DETERMINE THE COMPOUND AMOUNT FOR EACH TERM (STILL A WORK IN PROGRESS)
    term_1 = principal * rate * time
    new_amount_term_1 = term_1 + principal
    # Term_2 = New_Amount_Term_1 * rate * time_i
    # New_Amount_Term_2 = Term_2 + New_Amount_Term_1
```

THE CONCEPT HERE IS TO CREATE FUNCTIONS THAT ARE CALLED DEPENDING ON WHAT THE USER WANTS TO CALCULATE. I LEFT OUT ALL THE DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS AS I DONT THINK THEY ARE NEEDED.

```
# LETS FIGURE OUT WHAT THEY WANT TO DO
print("Welcome! What are we calculating today?")
print("Make a wise choice!")
print("1 - Interest")
print("2 - Fahrenheit")
print("3 - Celsius")  # THIS IS THE ONLY DIFFERENT ONE BECAUSE WE ONLY NEED ONE TO RECEIVE INPUT
print("4 - Circumference")  # ALSO THAT WAS THE ONE I ADDED INPUT TO THEN ADDED MORE FUNCTIONS SO YEAH...
print("5 - Area (Circle)")
print("6 - Area (Box)")
Answer_1 = int(input("7 - Perimeter (box)"))


# NOW LETS FIGURE OUT WHAT THEY CHOSE AND MOVE OVER TO THAT SECTION
if Answer_1 == 1:
    calc_int()
elif Answer_1 == 2:
    calc_fahr()
elif Answer_1 == 3:
    calc_cel()
elif Answer_1 == 4:
    calc_cir()
elif Answer_1 == 5:
    calc_area_circle()
elif Answer_1 == 6:
    calc_area_box()
elif Answer_1 == 7:
    calc_per_box()
```

I need the code to ask for another calculation upon finishing the first instead of just ending after the first calculation as it currently does.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add another condition to exit if you want to keep looping. Lets say user can enter 0 to exit. Then you can use the below code.

```
while True:
    # LETS FIGURE OUT WHAT THEY WANT TO DO
    print("Welcome! What are we calculating today?")
    print("Make a wise choice!")
    print("1 - Interest")
    print("2 - Fahrenheit")
    print("3 - Celsius")  # THIS IS THE ONLY DIFFERENT ONE BECAUSE WE ONLY NEED ONE TO RECEIVE INPUT
    print("4 - Circumference")  # ALSO THAT WAS THE ONE I ADDED INPUT TO THEN ADDED MORE FUNCTIONS SO YEAH...
    print("5 - Area (Circle)")
    print("6 - Area (Box)")
    Answer_1 = int(input("7 - Perimeter (box)"))


    # NOW LETS FIGURE OUT WHAT THEY CHOSE AND MOVE OVER TO THAT SECTION
    if Answer_1 == 1:
        calc_int()
    elif Answer_1 == 2:
        calc_fahr()
    elif Answer_1 == 3:
        calc_cel()
    elif Answer_1 == 4:
        calc_cir()
    elif Answer_1 == 5:
        calc_area_circle()
    elif Answer_1 == 6:
        calc_area_box()
    elif Answer_1 == 7:
        calc_per_box()
    elif Answer_1 == 0:
        break
```

Comment: You my friend are sent from the Gods!! Thanks!!